# Argument of type "datetime" cannot be assigned to parameter "value" of type "str"

Tags: python, mysql, datetime

I am currently working on a Python and SQL project.

There I am building a GUI that takes information from user input and stores them in a MySQL database locally.

There are a few warnings/errors that I am trying to resolve.

#### This is my code

Annotated the error-raising lines by comments.

```
elif (x == "Learn Python The Hard Way"):
    self.book_id_var.set("Book Id: 2")
    self.book_title_var.set("Learn Python The Hard Way")
    self.book_author_var.set("Zde A. Sham")

    d1 = datetime.datetime.today()
    d2 = datetime.timedelta(days = 15)
    d3 = d1 + d2

    self.date_borrowed_var.set(d1) # Argument of type "datetime" cannot be assigned to parameter "value" of type "str" in function "set", "datetime" is incompatible with "str"

    self.date_due_var.set(d3) # Argument of type "datetime" cannot be assigned to parameter "value" of type "str" in function "set", "datetime" is incompatible with "str"

    self.days_on_book_var.set("15")
    self.late_return_fine_var.set("Rs.25")
    self.date_over_due_var.set("NO")
    self.final_price_var.set("Rs.725")
```

In line 10 and 13, `d1` and `d3` are throwing the error commented. Unfortunately, I am not able to find solution to it.

Can I ignore *"datetime" is incompatible with "str"*, and if not, what would be a workaround?

Comment: Can you show the definition (type) of `date_borrowed_var` and `date_due_var`? Please [edit] your question, add those fields' definition and state what you intend with `set` here.

Comment: Is it okay if you convert d1 to str before you set it? self.date_borrowed_var.set(str(d1))

Comment: Maybe you should just add your complete class definition (including all fields) that `self` references to. This would be more a [example].

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to cast your datetime object to string you can call the .strftime method builtin to the datetime package

e.g. use:

```
d3.strftime("%d.%m.%y")
```

instead of just

```
d3
```

same goes for d1 - ("%d.%m.%y") represents the format in which your datetime is being represented.

Results would look like this:

```
self.date_borrowed_var.set(d1.strftime("%d.%m.%y"))
self.date_due_var.set(d3.strftime("%d.%m.%y"))
```

Comment: Although string-formatting and a cast might be a work-around, I doubt it is a helpful solution here. Let's clarify first, what is really intended by the code in question. For example, are you sure about the string-representation expected by the target-field ?

Comment: I see where you're coming from - but regarding the error or warning message he posted "datetime" is incompatible with "str" - I belive that a string is expected to be passed to the set function

Comment: Exactly, the error-message suggests that the field is of type `str`. But see the currency `"Rs."` for fines and ask about the localized date-format or ISO-formats. Even better to suggest using `datetime` as type for the fields and represent as string only when printing some text. This way don't need `str` as assignment-mediator and could explain assignment by (good) example: `self.date_borrowed = datetime.datetime.today()`

Comment: Thank you all for your responses, the solution from @Chris solved my problem. Also, sorry for my late response, I actually did respond 10 days ago but I have no clue what for my comment is not present, so I decided to write again! It was pleasure to read all of your possible solution to my problem!

Comment: @NikolaRistoski happy that I could help - would be cool if you could accept and upvote my answer in this case ;)